# How to render multiple sizes of same image in web app?

Tags: css, image, local-storage, rendering, avatar

I need to display the same image in multiple pages in different sizes. Like a user photo would show 60x60px in user listing page whilst the same photo will show 400x400 in User Profile page. Also, a product photo would be 100x100px in listing page whilst it'll be 240x240 in product detail page. I'd also require a 400x400px for in case the product is featured on the home page. I'm confused whether to:

1. Save multiple copies(avatars) of the same image and store their address in database.
   Or
2. Save only the original copy and use CSS to show them everywhere.

What is the best practice to saving images and rendering them efficiently?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I would save the picture in multiple sizes, because if you load a list with all users it is not recommend to load the big picture and resize them with css. It is better to load more images that would have a smaller size.

You can use suffixes like:

user123_64.png

user123_32.png

Comment: Thanks, I agree. What if you've to save many copies: for web, iOS and Android sets etc? And, would you store all avatar addresses as well on DB?

Comment: I would like to save the default sizes like (32x32, 64x64, 128x128, 256x256 and 512x512) for the avatars and if you must customise the size again then I would to do this with css. - In the database I would only save the standard link and put the suffix in the code.

Comment: It just seems the right way to do; I'll try this approach and let you know.